# Root Cause for an intermittent UnknownHostException from Java Service?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I have a `Java 8` `Spring Boot` service.

It is hosted on `AWS`, in `Kubernetes v1.13`, `Docker v18.06.3-ce`.

Yesterday for 10 or even more hours I had a bunch of intermittent `UnknownHostExceptions` when trying to send `http` requests from my service to both internal and external services.

The exception happened at least for 5 different host names.

Today I had no issues.

In the service logs I can not find anything other than something like this:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: example.com

Also, not sure if it is relevant, but the service is using `Spring Boot` `Apache Camel v2.22.0` to send these requests. Here is a piece of code which sends them:

```
    Exchange exchange = template.send(url, exchange1 -> {
        exchange1.getIn().setHeaders(headers);
        exchange1.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, httpMethod.toString());
        exchange1.getIn().setBody(body);
    });
```

`Mvn` dependencies for `Apache Camel`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-script</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas what can be the cause of these intermittent `UnknownHostExceptions`? Please let me know what pieces of info would be helpful to find out the root cause of the issue.

P.S. Service was working fine for more than a year. No recent code changes. At least for this logic above.

Comment: Gennerally, UnkownHostException are throw when a service, databse, server or anything else are unreachable. Your java program cannot access it. That sounds obvious, you might know that already. Well, I'm trying to say isn't it possible to be a infrastructure level problem? The service was offline, another network, a network rule for example?

Comment: Is it exactly `example.com` in your logs? If not, and there is your specific hostname - try `nslookup` and `dig` or `ping` of that host.

Comment: No, it is bunch of different host names. My service making requests to more than 50 different other external services.